# Trying to make sense with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I recently discovered React and I'm trying to understand how it works.
I put this code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Super simple, but my page is blank instead of showing h1 element I suposedly rendered here.
Can someone explain why doesn't it work and what am I missing to make it work?

There is also a simple element in the HTML file along with all instructed code from the React doc page:

```
<div id="app"></div>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Stack Snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
```

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: @Inder - The code shows v18.

Comment: is this create-react-app?

Comment: Latest, 18.0.0
It's not a create-react-app (deliberately)

Comment: @JDS - I've copied your code into a Stack Snippet and it seems to work (although note that it gives you a warning because `ReactDOM.render` has been replaced with a slightly different mechanism.)

Comment: I'm trying to understand why it doesn't render the element on a live server.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder am I using a wrong way to run the page? Because live server isn't showing anything.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't look at index.html, Also, class component is being used. Thats why asked !!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you don't have anything in place to handle JSX. Note that `<App />` is invalid JavaScript syntax. It's a JavaScript *extension* called [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). [You don't have to use JSX with React](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html), but most people do.

If you want to use JSX, you'll need to use Babel or similar to compile (aka "transpile") the JSX into calls to `React.createElement`. Usually you do that as a build step so that what's deployed is already transpiled (and minified and bundled). There is an in-browser way of doing it with [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone), but it's (strongly) not recommended for production. ([This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets) shows using Babel standalone.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I dug a little and found an online babel transpiler. It works now and I somewhat understand why :)
Still, a lot of digging is due.

Comment: Here's a link if anyone comes across this post in the future: [Babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.21&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=Q&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=react%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.17.9&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

Comment: @JDS - I did mention and link to Babel in the answer. :-) FWIW, I've been really enjoying using https://vitejs.dev/ lately. Create a project in Node.js, install vite, react, and react-dom, create an index.html and an index.jsx (or whatever), and `vite` will just figure it out. More: https://pastebin.com/mVMnXZ8Y